# Encrpyt URL Id in django

Tags: django, url, encryption

I was trying to excrypt Update URL id to encrpyted format in the url.

from my profile page of a user one edit button is there. that button contains url of the update view.

#My profile page. code

```
def profile(request):
    lst = request.user.id #This line is the problem
    l=[]
    for i in lst:
        i['encrypt_key']=encrypt(i['id'])
        i['id']=i['id']
        l.append(i)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'lst':l})
```

#The update view code

```
def update(request, id):
    id=decrypt(id)
    #Update code.
    return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', context)
```

In the profile page for that edit button, since it is an iteratable for loop
I coded like this is the Html template

```
<li class="ctx-item">
          <button class="ctx-menu-btn icon-box">
                      <span class="material-symbols-rounded  icon" aria-hidden="true">edit</span>
                      {% for x in lst %}
                      <span class="ctx-menu-text"><a href="/update/{{x.encrypt_key}}">Edit</a></span>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </button>
                  </li>
```

Since three users are there in my database, three edit links are coming. To restrict it in the profile view I have to change the filteration while retriving the user in lst.

If i put request.user.id, It is showing the following error.

```
TypeError at /profile/
'int' object is not iterable
```

Please help me to correct this error.

Comment: What do you want to put in the `lst` variable? Is it a list of users?? To me that seems you are storing a mere user id in the lst variable and you are trying to iterate on something that is just a plain interger, which in this case is a single user id. Perhaps you want to iterate through a list of user ids or user objects return from a queryset??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filtration answer is:

```
def profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        lst = User.objects.filter(username=request.user).values('id') #working
        l=[]
        for i in lst:
            i['encrypt_key']=encrypt(i['id'])
            i['id']=i['id']
            l.append(i)
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'lst':l})
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Please Provide the credentials to Login to your account.')
        return redirect("login")
```